# NDK debugging fails with gdbserver error: "Function <foo_bar> not defined"

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, gdk

NDK debugging on Windows fails.
I use Cygwin and gdb to debug native code.

I can attach debugger to an app process, but then I receive errors:

```
gdbserver: symbol is not loaded
```

and a dialog with following message: `"Error stopping at Java_***_*** Reason: Target request failed: Function <foo_ber> not defined".`
Do you have any ideas? Thanks.